# Developing on localhost for Google Apps Marketplace

Tags: oauth, localhost, google-apps-marketplace

My typical workflow is that I develop on localhost, but with Google Apps Marketplace this hasn't been possible. OpenID works fine, but access to Data APIs via Oauth results in errors.

```
Token invalid - Invalid token: ACL not found for domain: 358xxxxxxxxx and consumer: 736xxxxxxxxx
```

Currently I have been using the following workflow, but it is very tiresome.

**local** develop » **local** push to github » **remote** pull from github » **remote** test » *repeat*

**Is there a way to develop locally or another suggested workflow?**

---

**Solution:**

A mashup of @koma and @JTeagle suggestions, I have **multiple branches with Oauth keys in each config respective of the branch**. I also created a **unique localhost domain my_project.dev** which satisfies Google's requirements (since their localhost trigger wasn't working for me)

Comment: I assume your question is... 'Is there another way?'  What kind of errors have you experienced using OAuth via localhost?

Comment: Thank you for the input on the question. So far I have tried to create a unpublished application under My-Vendor-Profile which pointed to localhost but it didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I've managed to get Google APIs to give me an access token back via a localhost connection via OAuth2 but I fear it's not a similar enough process for me to be able to help you here. In my case I had a client ID and secret, obtained via Google's API Console, which made it possible for it to send me back the token via a local socket... is that even close to the way you're trying to access the data APIs / use the token mentioned?

Comment: Yea I was looking at that but it is for Google Accounts right not for Google App domains? I guess I could build it with both features as to get the functionality working and then just implement the Marketplace keys when needed. Is that wise, having two sets of keys?

Comment: Having seen the previous Q of yours that spawned this one, yes, it seems Apps and Accounts are distinctly separate. I'm a newbie to the world of Google APIs myself. Given that the API Console seems to expect you to generate client IDs and secrets *per application* (although you can generate just one for your organisation if you want), I don't see any problem having multiple keys; it's just a maintenance / data confidentiality issue for you, which is no worse than the tedium you're suffering at the moment having that large round trip to try and test your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what github as to do with it, but if I understand well, it is difficult to do OAUTH on localhost. That is indeed cumbersome.

My solution for this problem is to register my dynamic DNS domainname in the Google Api Console and then do port forwarding on the router to my development machine.

This way, your development environment can do all the OAUTH requests and the callbacks from Google hit the router, and I can debug them.

Comment: github has nothing to do with it, just explaining my workflow... JTeagle brings upa good point of managing the multiple API keys within the repo

Comment: Yes I do the same, multiple keys. one for development which is linked to my DynDNS. Then port forwarding on the router to catch the callbacks from Google so you can at least debug.

Comment: I did something similar. Using OSX bind I've created http://my_project.dev which satisfies the need of Google and now I can develop for Google Marketplace locally. I also have keys created for staging.my_project.com and my_project.com in their respective branches.